# How do I make my Python program search up my questions on Google (based on a certain input)?

Tags: python, google-chrome, raspberry-pi, voice

I am trying to make a voice assistant like program, in which questions are asked, and questions that cannot be answered by the program are searched by Google.com. So I was simply wondering **what softwares I would have to install to make this work?** And what would I generally have to do to?

For more information, I am using **Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi 3 B**, and I am using **Python 3.9.2**

Thank you!

Comment: use Google API, also you can't seek recommendations for software and tools here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a few libraries and nothing else to install. A great tutorial is found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/

The two libraries needed are:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and

```
pip install google
```

Comment: @RyanShirvani I'm not sure if this is what you need but I found this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/scrape-and-summarize-news-articles-in-5-lines-of-python-code-175f0e5c7dfc

In the article, they are able to load the website with just the link.

Comment: @RyanShirvani I found a 2nd article that uses a different library to display the website:https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+display+a+webpage+in+python